# C#, messages supposed to be among each other

Tags: c#, string, button, textbox, richtextbox

i created a windows forms-app with visual studio and im programming in c#.

I have one textbox, one richtextbox and one button. If im writing something in the textbox and press the button, the text from the textbox is shown in the richtextbox (just like a simple chat). My problem is, that if i already wrote something and add something new, the old text in the richtextbox gets replaced by the new one. I want that everything i wrote is among each other.
My source code:

```
string message = textbox1.Text;
richTextBox1.Text = "Name:" + message;
```

Comment: Maybe `richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine + "Name:" + message;` ?

Comment: have you tried appending or prepending instead of replacing? you know how to concatenate strings, so you know everything you need to know.

Comment: @tnw it worked, perfect thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Of course; you set the Text of the richtextbox to a new text each time you access it

Consider using `richTextBox1.AppendText(message)` instead

Answer (score 2):

Using the equals operator replaces the value in the `.Text` property. If you'd like to *append* text, use the `+=` operator:

```
string message = textbox1.Text;
richTextBox1.Text += "Name:" + message;
```

Alternatively, you can skip the shorthand and say:

```
string message = textbox1.Text;
richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "Name:" + message;
```

Or, use `AppendText()`:

```
richTextBox1.AppendText(message)
```

Comment: No worries. Don't forget to upvote and mark as answer.

Comment: @mxy, If this answer helped you, please consider marking it as the accepted answer by click on the check mark next to the answer.